# Typo in PyMongo $set/update causes TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Tags: python-3.x, pymongo

I'm going to answer this myself.  Just adding in case someone else hits the same issue.

```
find_query = {'_id': doc['_id']}
upd_statement = {'$set:',
                 {'subdivision_name': new_name}
                 }
dbCollection.update_one(find_query, upd_statement, upsert=False)
```

Error:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following line, I had a comma instead of a colon (and I also had the colon inside the quotes, which would have been a later issue).

```
upd_statement = {'$set':
                    { 'subdivision_name':  new_name}
                }
```

Sometimes when typing fast and switching between JSON and other formatting, I mess up the JSON...  Or can happen when copying non-PyMongo examples into Python.